# How to clear / reset input[type=file] after uploading a file?

Tags: nightwatch.js

After uploading a file, it remains in the input. If a second file is uploaded, the first one is "sticking" to the input and will be uploaded again - together with the current one. How can you reset / clear the input in nightwatch.js?

I have tried to clear the input `.clearValue('@fileUpload')` and tried to set an empty value `.setValue('@fileUpload', '')`. Unfortunately, both did not work.

I am using page objects and this i how i upload files:

```
sectionMediaContent.setValue('@fileUpload', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/../../../../etc/upload/audioMedium/01_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Mono_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB.mp3'));
```

Used environment:

```
chromedriver: "76.0.1"
nightwatch: "1.2.2"
```

I am grateful for any help and please let me know if more information is required.

Here ist the one of the test cases:

```
  'Upload and check audio media files': function (browser) {
    const pageLogin = browser.page.login();
    const sectionLogin = pageLogin.section.login;

    const pageNodes = browser.page.nodes();
    const sectionNodesTree = pageNodes.section.tree;

    const pageMedia = browser.page.media();
    const sectionMediaContent = pageMedia.section.content;

    // Select media pool of root
    sectionNodesTree
      .nodePoolsArePresent('Root')
      .selectNode('@nodeMediaPoolOfRoot');
    sectionMediaContent.waitForElementVisible('@contentTitle', browser.globals.visibleTimeout)

    // Upload audio media file types
    sectionMediaContent.setValue('@fileUpload', require('path').resolve(
      __dirname + '/../../../../etc/upload/audioMedium/01_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Mono_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB.mp3' + '\n' +
      __dirname + '/../../../../etc/upload/audioMedium/02_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Stereo_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB.mp3'));

    // TODO: remove this workaround / reload page to reset input type file
    browser.pause(1000);
    browser.refresh();
    sectionNodesTree
      .waitForElementPresent('@nodeMediaPoolOfRoot')
      .selectNode('@nodeMediaPoolOfRoot');
    sectionMediaContent.waitForElementVisible('@contentTitle');

    // Check uploaded media file types in media table
    sectionMediaContent.checkMediumTable('@media1Row', {
      type: 'Audio',
      title: '01_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Mono_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB',
    });

    sectionMediaContent.checkMediumTable('@media2Row', {
      type: 'Audio',
      title: '02_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Stereo_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB',
    });

    // Check uploaded audio media file type details
    sectionMediaContent.checkMedium('@media1Row', {
      type: 'Audio',
      title: '01_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Mono_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB',
      fileName: '01_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Mono_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB.mp3',
      fileType: 'MP3 Audio',
      fileSize: '10,57 KB',
      audioLength: '00:02 Min.',
      audioChannels: 'Mono',
      audioSampleRate: '22,05 kHz',
      audioBitRate: '40,00 KBit/s',
    });

    sectionMediaContent.checkMedium('@media2Row', {
      type: 'Audio',
      title: '02_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Stereo_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB',
      fileName: '02_audioMedium_MP3_L-0.02Min_B-40kBits_C-Stereo_SR-22.05kHz_S-10.5KB.mp3',
      fileType: 'MP3 Audio',
      fileSize: '10,57 KB',
      audioLength: '00:02 Min.',
      audioChannels: 'Stereo',
      audioSampleRate: '22,05 kHz',
      audioBitRate: '40,00 KBit/s',
    });
  },
```

And here is a snippet out of the page object

```
        // Media file upload
        fileUpload: 'input[type=file]',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but can you try with ids rather than with `@fileUpload`. Try `.execute` instead of `clearValue`.
https://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html

```
<input type="file" id="something" />
.execute(function() {
  document.getElementById("something").value = ''
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint @raman, I have tested your suggestion `.clearValue('#input-id')` and get the same error as when using `.clearValue('@fileUpload')`. It says "Error while running .clearElementValue() protocol action: element not interactable". So it makes no difference if i am using a page object element `fileUpload: 'input[type=file]',` or directly the id (in my case `#field_files`) as selector.

Comment: Every other idea for a solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: hello @Skuubi80, i have edit the answer to a different approach. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Hi @raman, many thanks for suggesting another approach. I have tested it:
`browser.execute(function() {document.getElementById('#field_files').value = ''});` this results in an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null". I get what you want to try and tried this `browser.execute(function() {document.querySelectorAll('#field_files').value = ''});` this results in no error but did not clear/reset the input field. So i need to test and research further.

Comment: @Skuubi80, Can you post a codepan or a jsfiddle of the code? I would like to take a crack at it.

Comment: I found a dirty way to deal with the problem. After an upload, I reload the page with  `browser.refresh()` which resets the input. Could not imagine anything uglier, but it's the best I've got right now.

Comment: i have edited my first post and added a sample test case. It consists the ugly reset-input-by-reloading-page-workaround. In this test suite, 7 supported file types are beeing tested (audio, document, image, spreadsheet, presentation, file, video). Tell me when more infos are needed.

Comment: After a meeting with a colleague and various tests we came to a working solution.

    // Clear file input
    browser.execute(function () {
        document.getElementById('field_files').value = '';
    });

Which was exactly the proposed solution from [raman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1909446/raman). However, I used it with querySelectorAll, which returned me a list instead of the element.